# Styled-component object can't observe mobx changes

Tags: javascript, mobx, styled-components, mobx-react

I would like an HOC generated by [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) to re-render when one of its properties get changed. I'm using MobX for change detection.

This doesn't respond to changes, I think I understand why. The question is if there is a simple workaround to make it work.

```
const DemoComponent = observer(styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.myObject.myObservableIsTrue ? 'red' : 
'green'};
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell by this little snippet, but one of my guesses would be you are not injecting any store, so currently, no store is being connected to your component.

here's a simple example of how I used styled-components with mobx if it helps:

**EDITED:**
I've updated the code example.

Do you know the Container / Presentational pattern?
This was the missing link.

In order to keep your renders as little as possible
you need to separate your stateful component from each other.
Spread them across a Container component (aka Dumb Components)

This way you separate state concerns and render only the component with the changed state.

**UPDATED:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/zxx6o2pq3l

Comment: My snippet is only a simplified example. I edited your example to demonstrate the problem again: https://react-shubzp.stackblitz.io . The point is that in your example the whole `App` is rendered again when the color get changed. I wanted to avoid that, and only to render `Wrapper`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to reduce the number of renders. Take a look in `OtherComponent` in your example. Every time you click the "change color" button, it will re-render. Can we agree on that? But that is too much - rendering `Wrapper` is enough. So I'm trying to achieve this goal. In my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-shubzp , "change color" doesn't work. My question is if it's possible to make it working without changing the props passed into Wrapper.

Comment: Look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxx6o2pq3l
stackblitz crashed so i couldnt update

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!!! A bit of a hack job, but attempt to bring your entire code inside the @inject("store") class:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

@inject("store")
@observer
export default class OtherComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const MyWrapper = (store) => {
      const Wrapper = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: ${({ color }) => color};
  border: 2px solid ${({ color }) => color || "black"};
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;
      return (
        <Wrapper {...store}>
          styled-component
        <button onClick={store.changeColor}>change color</button>
        </Wrapper>
      );
    }
    const { store } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      {
          MyWrapper(store)
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Mobx is actually read like this: @inject("store") @observer export default class...

So it really an extension of an extended component; only wrapped variables will apply!

Comment: Nice, but it's a bit cheating :) By declaring `Wrapper` inside `OtherComponent` render function you're making it completely useless elsewhere. So Wrapper isn't a "real" component now.

Comment: @gamliela Thanks! My point is to merely bring the Wrapper inside the injection. Then you then substitute "OtherComponent" for "Wrapper", then import Wrapper from "./WrapperComponent.
Mobx will automatically update the component from the store; therefore, you will not have to pass it any arguments.

Comment: Ohh I see your point now. Yeah, that's valid I guess although not really efficient and I wouldn't consider that as a "simple workaround". Since you're creating a new component class every render, I'm not sure if that's approach is practical.